# Clicking register causes android app to crash

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext

Clicking on register makes the app crash when the email and password fields are empty, but when the name field is empty it works properly what seems to be the problem?

xml file:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash.LoginActivity"
android:background="#fff"
>

<!-- Login progress -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_ewallet_" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reg_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="20sp"
            android:paddingRight="20sp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Already have an account?"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

code:

```
package com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
 private EditText reg_password,
  reg_username,
  reg_email;
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext());
    reg_password = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    reg_email    = findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    reg_username = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    findViewById(R.id.register).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.signin).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    final String username = reg_username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = reg_email.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = reg_password.getText().toString().trim();


    if (username.equals("")) {
        reg_username.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_name));
        reg_username.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (email.equals("")) {
        reg_email.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email));
        reg_email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }else{
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            reg_email.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email_invalid));
            reg_email.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
    }

    if (password.equals("")) {
        reg_password.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_password));
        reg_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }else{
    if (password.length() < 8) {
            reg_password.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_password_length));
            reg_password.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
    }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            User user = new User(
                                    username,
                                    email
                            );

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, getString(R.string.registration_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, getString(R.string.registration_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.register:
                registerUser();
            break;
        case R.id.signin:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

error log:

```
09-03 13:25:24.942 15875-15875/com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash, PID: 15875
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:492)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:955)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:872)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:75)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.widget.Editor.showError(Editor.java:505)
at android.widget.Editor.onFocusChanged(Editor.java:1237)
at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:9821)
at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:6631)
at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:10890)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10869)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10836)
at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:10778)
at com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:74)
at com.example.zachmarcelo.softcash.RegisterActivity.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:143)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

and this is what is supposed to be happening: (works perfectly in name text but not in other edittexts)

[screenshot of mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W87hP.png)

any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: Can you paste the error log?

Comment: edited it @UmangBurman

Comment: Looks to me that there is a problem in your TextView, Can you paste entire xml and Java code please. So that I can help you with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it has something to do with what you put into `@style/TextLabel`.

When you have an error with password or email you request focus programmatically. Which is fine, however when that happens something in your style is looking for a color resource which doesn't exist. That's what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be for getColor() method of textview, your primary color has some problem, please check that.

Comment: there is no problem with the textview. the problem is with the EditTexts. thanks for your answer